# How can I prevent iframe infinite loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a "component" for my website to show users how it looks on responsive views, and for this I have made several iframes to be displayed on devices to simulate its being used on an iPhone for example.

Now, the problem is that the iframe code is being displayed on every page, so if I make the iframe display my website it will again see that there is an iframe inside of it and it wont stop loading the page, it creates sort of an "iframe loop" that makes the page never load.

Does anyone have any idea on how to prevent this? Maybe just making the iframes load once?

Comment: just use frame busting code to make sure the main page is never framed.